# How to switch Selenium focus within an iframe using Python

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, webdriverwait, expected-condition

I am unable to select a checkbox from a drop down menu on site. The dropdown is inside a iframe and when i try and switch to the iframe i keep getting `TimeoutException` message:.

Below is the code I'm trying and the HTML. I am new to Python so any help on this would be much appreciated.

Python:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

frm1= wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ctl01")))

driver.switch_to.frame(frm1)
```

HTML:

```
<iframe id="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ctl01" onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;" onactivate="event.cancelBubble=true;" style="display: block; position: absolute; z-index: 10; left: 208px; top: 35px; width: 198px; height: 166px;" src="javascript:'';" frameborder="0" title="Area place holder" longdesc="Area place holder" name="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ctl01"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To switch [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491)'s focus within the `<iframe>` instead of `presence_of_element_located()` so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[name^='ReportViewerControl'][longdesc='Area place holder']")))
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[starts-with(@id, 'ReportViewerControl') and @title='Area place holder']")))
    ```
  - **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

    ```
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)

Comment: Thanks I figured it out there was an iframe outside the iframe i was trying to switch to. I just had to switch to the main iframe first then it let me switch to the iframe above.